# "calabash-android run apk" pass env variables containing space

Tags: android, cucumber, environment-variables, batch-processing, calabash

I am running calabash test cases using the following command in command prompt(Windows). I need to pass a few environment variables to the test cases. I am able to pass variables "IP_ADDRESS, USER_EMAIL" as below. But cannot pass USER_NAME variable as it contains space in it.

```
calabash-android run myApp.apk IP_ADDRESS=192.168.30.169 USER_EMAIL=xyz@abc.com USER_NAME=bruce wayne
```

I have tried passing the variable in single quotes, double quotes, and also appending an escape character("\") before space. But every time it throws me an error

```
"No such file or directory - wayne. Please create a wayne directory to get started.
 (Errno::ENOENT)"
```

Please help me suggest a way to pass these environment variables along with the run command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following solution:

```
set IP_ADDRESS=192.168.30.169
set USER_EMAIL=xyz@abc.com
set USER_NAME='bruce wayne'
calabash-android run myApp.apk
```

Then variables should be available in the test as well.

Comment: It gives an error, <'IP_ADDRESS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.>

Comment: Yea, it worked thanks a ton.. :) Just that the quotes were not required.